# Django 'Sites' Model - what is and why is 'SITE_ID = 1'?

Tags: django, django-sites

I am trying to work with `Sites` Model of Django.

I dont quite understand why `SITE_ID` should be `SITE_ID = 1`.

in the docs:

> The ID, as an integer, of the current site in the django_site database
> table. This is used so that application data can hook into specific
> sites and a single database can manage content for multiple sites.

why `1`? what is the `current site`? this is not clearly explained in the docs.

lets say, I have `www.coolsite.com` and some other subdomains like `www.wow.coolsite.com` and `www.awesome.coolsite.com`

I want to render different content depending on domain name.

my question is, or better, are:

1. Do I have to add all those domains into `Sites` Table in DB?
2. if so, how should I set `SITE_ID` in settings? Do I have to set all ids like `SITE_ID = 1`, `SITE_ID = 2`.. etc?
3. what does `current site` has to do with `SITE_ID = 1`?

I am a bit confused here.

I thought, each Site (e.g. `www.wow.coolsite.com`) should be a separate django project so that they can have their own settings.py? and in each of those settings.py's, I will set the id of that page from Sites table? but then there are many django projects which also doesnot make sense to me.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Django was created from a set of scripts developed at a newspaper to publish content on multiple domains; using one single content base.

This is where the "sites" module comes in. Its purpose is to mark content to be displayed for different domains.

In previous versions of django, the `startproject` script automatically added the `django.contrib.sites` application to `INSTALLED_APPS`, and when you did `syncdb`, [a default site with the URL `example.com` was added to your database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sites/#default-site-and-syncdb), and since this was the first site, its ID was `1` and that's where the setting comes from.

Keep in mind that starting from 1.6, this framework is not enabled by default. So if you need it, you must [enable it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework)

The `SITE_ID` setting sets the *default* site for your project. So, if you [don't specify a site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sites/#getting-the-current-domain-for-display), this is the one it will use.

So to configure your application for different domains:

1. [Enable the sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework)
2. Change the default site from `example.com` to whatever your default domain is. You can do this from the django shell, or from the admin.
3. Add your other sites for which you want to publish content to the sites application. Again, you can do this from the django shell just like any other application or from the admin.
4. Add a foreign key to the Site model in your object `site = models.ForeignKey(Site)`
5. Add the site manager `on_site = CurrentSiteManager()`

Now, when you want to filter content for the default site, or a particular site:

```
foo = MyObj.on_site.all() # Filters site to whatever is `SITE_ID`
foo = MyObj.objects.all() # Get all objects, irrespective of what site
                          # they belong to
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework) has a full set of examples.

Comment: thanks, but i am not still sure about ``SITE_ID``. what if i have 3 sites? do i have to add all those 3 site ids into one single main settings.py? this doesnot make any sense to me right now :(

Comment: i think, each site should be a separate django project so that they can have their own settings.py? and in that settings.py, i will set the id of that page from ``Sites`` table? but then there are many django projects which also doesnot make sense to me :(

Comment: You don't create multiple projects, you just add all the domains to the sites database; then based on what the current domain is, you filter the content you want to show. Its a very simple, basic implementation.

Comment: django knows the current site depending on ``SITE_ID`` in settings.py, right? How can I have multiple ``SITE_ID``'s in a single settings.py and how can ``foo = MyObj.on_site.all()`` know what the current site is? sorry for many questions.

Comment: You have one SITE_ID in a settings file. Each site has its own server. On each server you set a different DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, picking up a different settings, hence a different SITE_ID.

Answer (score 23):

Things would be much easier to understand if Django's default SiteAdmin included the id field in the `list_display` fields.

To do this, you can redefine SiteAdmin (anywhere in your app, but I'd recommend your admin.py or maybe your urls.py) like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

admin.site.unregister(Site)
class SiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'domain')
    readonly_fields = ('id',)
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'domain')
    list_display_links = ('name',)
    search_fields = ('name', 'domain')
admin.site.register(Site, SiteAdmin)
```

After including this code snippet, the ID for each "Site" will be shown in the first column of the admin list and inside the form as a read only field. These 'id' fields are what you need to use as SITE_ID:

[image: modified admin page showing Site records' id]

The concept is that each different site runs in a different application server instance, launched using a different yourdomain_settings.py that then includes a base_settings.py with the rest of the common configuration.

Each of these yourdomain_settings.py will define its own SITE_ID and all other different settings.py parameters that they need to look and be different from each other (static resources, templates, etc.) then you'll [define a DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable pointing to that specific yourdomain_settings.py file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE) when launching the application server instance for that domain.

A further note: `get_current_site(request)` does need `request` to be available for it to work. If your code doesn't have one, you can use `Site.objects.get_current()` that however will need a SITE_ID properly defined in the running application server's settings.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Django's documentation is not clear enough to make me sure it's intended to be used like that. Sometimes it's worth going to the last answer ;)

Answer (score 7):

This is a late answer but for anyone else having SITE_ID issues and Site problems.
Inside the database, django has a django_site table with(id, domain, name). This is where django stores the SITE_IDs. Mine was actually 5 in the database but i had it set to SITE_ID=1 in the settings.

Knowing that, i can now go back to the database and clear it to get back to zero or use the actual id in the database.

Answer (score 5):

This is covered in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework) for the Sites framework:

> In order to serve different sites in production, you’d create a
>   separate settings file with each SITE_ID (perhaps importing from a
>   common settings file to avoid duplicating shared settings) and then
>   specify the appropriate DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE for each site.

But if you didn't want to do it that way, you can not set `SITE_ID` at all and just look up the current site based on the domain name in your views using `get_current_site`:

```
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site

def my_view(request):
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    if current_site.domain == 'foo.com':
        # Do something
        pass
    else:
        # Do something else.
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://siliconloop.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-use-django-sites-framework.html) explains it:

> You’ll want to create separate settings files for each domain you’re adding; each one will need its own MEDIA_URL and other settings. You’ll also want to do two things to make sure everything works out properly for administering the different sites:
>
> Create a new Site object in your admin for each domain, and put the id of that Site into its settings file as SITE_ID so Django knows which site in the database corresponds to this settings file.
>
> In the settings file for your original site (the one with id 1), add the other sites’ settings files to the ADMIN_FOR setting, to let Django know that this one instance of the admin application will handle all of the sites.

Also, if you wanna figure out how to modify models and set the views You may take a look at this link:
https://django.cowhite.com/blog/managing-multiple-websites-with-a-common-database-in-django-the-sites-framework/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

"Sites" was initially intended for multiple servers sharing a DB, but was extended [with feature #15089](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15089) around version 1.4 to support basic multitenancy.

Nowadays you can simply not define `SITE_ID` if you always use methods that take a `request`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).