# Django project on two domains - limiting access to urls/views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am working on django project.
It utilizes multiple small apps - where one of them is used for common things (common models, forms, etc).

I want to separate whole for project to two domains, i.g.:

corporatedomain.com and userportal.com

I want corporatedomain.com to use different urls, same for userportal.com.

Is that possible? If so, how can I do this? How should I configure my urls?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can look at the `Django Site Framework`. From Django official documentation:

> Django comes with an optional “sites” framework. It’s a hook for associating objects and functionality to particular Web sites, and it’s a holding place for the domain names and “verbose” names of your Django-powered sites.

You can use then this approach

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

current_site = Site.objects.get_current()

if 'userportal' in current_site.domain:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'', include('userapp.urls')),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
else:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'', include('corporateapp.urls')),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
```

You should add as many entries as you need to Site Table and add `django.contrib.sites` app in your INSTALLED_APP and also a SITE_ID variable to your settings bound with the correct site ID. Use SITE_ID = 1 when no domain info are available (for example in your development session). More info about SITE_ID in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468676/django-sites-model-what-is-and-why-is-site-id-1)).
In my settings I use the following approach:

```
SITE_ID = os.environ.get('SITE_ID', 1)
```

where I have set the right SITE_ID variable in each of my enrivorments.

Answer (score 0):

You will have separate settings file anyway so define different `ROOT_URLCONF` for each domain.

**UPDATE**: If you don't want to use different settings then you have to write the middleware which will change the [`request.urlconf`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) attribute using the `HTTP_HOST` header.  Here is the [example of such middleware](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultiHostMiddleware).

Comment: How can I do this? :)

Comment: Do you have single settings file for both domains or use different settings for different domains?

Comment: Currently I have single settings.py file

Comment: Then it is time to have two :-)  But if you really want to use single settings for both domains then read the update in my answer.

Comment: Okay, If I want to use 2 settings files, where can I configure it? I mean, where I tell server to use particular settings for some domain?

Comment: It depends on your deployment configuration. You can pass the `--settings` parameter to the `manage.py` command or use the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---settings

Comment: Also this page is worth to read: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings#SimplePackageOrganizationforEnvironments