# PostgreSQL Django migrate error - domain already exits

Tags: django, postgresql

I've set up a new Django project (based on the template django cookie cutter) but get a postgres error when trying to migrate the database for the first time

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "django_site_domain_a2e37b91_uniq" already exists
```

I'm not clear what the issue is or how best to diagnose?

Comment: do you have SITE_ID in your settings?

Comment: thanks SITE_ID gave me the hint I needed, I had a collision with another project.

Comment: I have this exact problem and yet I only have one project. Could you please give me some detail on what to look for?

Comment: how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

### [What is SITE_ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468676/django-sites-model-what-is-and-why-is-site-id-1)?

> Django was created from a set of scripts developed at a newspaper to
>   publish content on multiple domains; using one single content base.
>
> This is where the "sites" module comes in. Its purpose is to mark
>   content to be displayed for different domains.
>
> In previous versions of django, the startproject script automatically
>   added the django.contrib.sites application to INSTALLED_APPS, and when
>   you did syncdb, a default site with the URL example.com was added to
>   your database, and since this was the first site, its ID was 1 and
>   that's where the setting comes from.
>
> Keep in mind that starting from 1.6, this framework is not enabled by
>   default. So if you need it, you must enable it
>
> The SITE_ID setting sets the default site for your project. So, if you
>   don't specify a site, this is the one it will use.

### Ways to fix this:

**Increment `SITE_ID`:**

```
1. Increment `SITE_ID` variable in settings.py
2. python manage.py makemigrations
3. python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

Cons: Had to increment SITE_ID without good reason

**Attempt to migrate without `--run-syncdb`:**

```
1. python manage.py makemigrations
2. python manage.py migrate
```

Note: May have to try multiple times before it works. Unsure why, possibly because I was in the process of deleting the [pvc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)

Comment: Additional note: It could be that the second step worked because I performed the first step beforehand - meaning the error occurs when the migration from SITE_ID 1 -> 1 but going 1 -> 2 then 2 -> 1 avoids the issue