# django-registration-redux is not working

Tags: python, django

django-registration-redux is not working. I have changed my settings to the following and run `python manage.py migrate`. I haven't got a clue why it hasn't done anything to the database, which is what is suggested in **Page not found** error?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',  # manually added
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # third party apps
    'crispy_forms',
    'registration',  # django-registration-redux
    #  my apps
        'newsletter',
    )

# Django-registration-redux settings
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True
```

[image]

Comment: are you add `url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),` in `urls.py`?

Comment: without this, it wouldn't recognize accounts/ stuff, so yes this has been done!

Comment: you're right, testing url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/` test url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/` and check if there is errors. `/accounts/` is the api root

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/` is giving a different error and it's not going to `^accounts/` at all `DoesNotExist at /accounts/login/`

Comment: Is the line you added manually `'django.contrib.sites'`, you shoud add in `settings.py` `SITE_ID = 1`. Read more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468676/django-sites-model-what-is-and-why-is-site-id-1

Answer (score 1):

I just thought I would post the solution to my problem if anybody encounters the same issue. The template `base.html` needs to be referenced to the correct folder if your templates are not stored in one folder, so it becomes `{% extends "folder/base.html" %}`. There are a couple of html files in `registration` folder with `base.html` needing re-referencing.