# Site matching query does not exist. Django/Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

My site appears to deploy correctly on heroku, I can access the main page fine but when I try to login or signup (which directs to a new page) I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 90, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 146, in dispatch
    return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 74, in dispatch
    response = super(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, self).dispatch(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 101, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 90, in get
    response = super(AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin, self).get(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 135, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 177, in get_context_data
    site = get_current_site(self.request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/shortcuts.py", line 13, in get_current_site
    return Site.objects.get_current(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py", line 58, in get_current
    return self._get_site_by_id(site_id)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py", line 30, in _get_site_by_id
    site = self.get(pk=site_id)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 439, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: Site matching query does not exist.
```

I am using `all-auth` for authentication purposes - but I am not sure why this error is being thrown.

Here is my settings.py

```
rom pathlib import Path
import os


from django.contrib.auth import login


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
[...]

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

LOGIN_URL = '/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

# Application definition

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                # `allauth` needs this from django
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# added this for all-auth
[...]



INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    
    #'shops',
    'testingland',
    'rest_framework',
    'bootstrap_modal_forms',

    # all auth
    # The following apps are required:
    # 'django.contrib.auth',
    # 'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

    'widget_tweaks',

]

#django-allauth registraion settings
[...]

# 1 day
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT = 86400 
  
SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'anybody1.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'anybody1.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'vygr',
        'USER': 'x',
        'PASSWORD': 'x',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}


[...]


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

[...]

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'

import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: I've had this problem TOO many times.  Just play around with `SITE_ID = 1` changing the number until it works!  By the way, when you deploy to Heroku, or anywhere, you should have `DEBUG = False`.

Comment: Really? What does changing the ``SITE_ID`` do? It does seem to feature a lot in people's responses to similar questions.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure.  i just know that I got *exactly* the same error when doing django-allauth and Google OAuth2 and that's the *exact* same error I got.  Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468676/django-sites-model-what-is-and-why-is-site-id-1, but again, I just know it will work if you keep playing with the number you provide.  `SITE_ID = 1` will work initially, but as you develop and change things the database will increment the `SITE_ID`.